# Why does the compiler say abstract environment not defined?

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass [10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{Abstract}
text here
\end{Abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be looking for the `abstract` environment, no cap.

Comment: Explaining what @Édouard pointed out: just about everything in LaTeX is case-sensitive; since `\begin{Env}` and `\end{Env}` basically resolve to `\Env` and `\endEnv`, the importance of case becomes evident.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the environment you’re looking for is `abstract`.

```
\documentclass [10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
text here
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

As Sean Allred explained in his comment, TeX (thus LaTeX) is **case-sensitive**. This means that `abstract` and `Abstract` designate two different environments, and the latter is undefined.

The document proves that LaTeX is case-sensitive:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mymacro{\LaTeX{} is case-sensitive.}
% Actually, if LaTeX was not case-sensitive, the next line would create an error
% (\newcommand would fail if \MYMACRO were already defined)
\newcommand\MYMACRO{\LaTeX{} is \textit{not} case-sensitive.}

\begin{document}

\mymacro

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass [10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{Abstract}
{\begin{abstract}}
{\end{abstract}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Abstract}
text here
\end{Abstract}

\end{document}
```